# Can ggplot2 geom_segment size be specified as a proportion of the axis size?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics, geom-segment

I have a geom_segment in a plot and would like its size to scale relative to the y axis.

For example:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(avg_sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = avg_sepal_length)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.5, y = 10, xend = 3.5, yend = 10), size = 20)
```

Produces a horizontal segment above the barchart at y=10 with a fixed size of 20 (mm I think). But when you resize the plot this stays 20 regardless of the size of the plot or the dimensions of the axis.

I've tried using scale_size_continuous() but can't seem to get the results I'm looking for.

Is there a way to set size so that it changes when the plot size changes?

edit:
attached exports of 200x200 and 1000x1000, you can see the segment height proportion is not maintained, the height of the segment is absolute.

[image: 200x200]
[image: 1000x1000]

Comment: I'm just manually resizing the viewer, or exporting at different sizes. I would like to export the plot at any size/resolution and the segment always be proportional. Currently if I export it at 100x100 or 1000x1000 they appear different. I suspect I might need to work out the exact scale that I works for me and only ever export at that size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT

To make consistent with `x` and `y`, you may want to try:

```
library(ggplot2)
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(avg_sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = avg_sepal_length)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0.5, xmax = 3.5, ymin = 10 - 0.5, ymax = 10 + 0.5))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea but not quite what I'm looking for. A better explanation is that I would like to be able to export the plot at any resolution and the proportions of the geom be maintained. I'm attached 2 examples in the original post showing what happens.

Comment: I see. Sorry I misunderstood your original question. You instructed `ggplot` to add a bar with fixed size and then resized the overall graph. `ggplot` did exactly what it is supposed to do -- keep the bar size fixed. Could please you revise your post and clarify your expected outcome?

Comment: I have revised my answer, please let me know if it is not what you were after.

Comment: That's perfect, geom_rect is a much better idea. Thank you.